# HorizontalPodAutoscaler scales up pods but then terminates them instantly

Tags: kubernetes

So I have a `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` set up for my backend (an fpm-server and an Nginx server for a Laravel application).

The problem is that when the `HPA` is under load, it scales up the pods but it terminates them instantly, not even letting them get into the **Running** state.

The metrics are good, the scale-up behavior is as expected the only problem is that the pods get terminated right after scaling.

What could be the problem?

**Edit:** The same `HPA` is used on the frontend and it's working as expected, the problem seems to be only on the backend.

**Edit 2:** I have `Cluster Autoscaler` enabled, it does it's job, nodes get added when they are needed and then cleaned up so it's not an issue about available resources.

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: fpm-server
  labels:
    tier: backend
    layer: fpm
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: backend
      layer: fpm
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: backend
        layer: fpm
    spec:
      {{- with .Values.imagePullSecrets }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}           
      containers:
        - name: fpm
          image: "{{ .Values.fpm.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.fpm.image.tag }}"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 9000
              protocol: TCP
          env:
          {{- range $name, $value := .Values.env }}
          - name: {{ $name }}
            value: "{{ $value }}" 
          {{- end }}             
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: backend-secrets
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
```

**hpa.yaml**

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: fpm-server-hpa
  labels:
    tier: backend
    layer: fpm
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: fpm-server
  minReplicas: {{ .Values.autoscaling.minReplicas }}
  maxReplicas: {{ .Values.autoscaling.maxReplicas }}
  metrics:
    {{- if .Values.autoscaling.targetCPUUtilizationPercentage }}
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: cpu
        targetAverageUtilization: {{ .Values.autoscaling.targetCPUUtilizationPercentage }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if .Values.autoscaling.targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage }}
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: memory
        targetAverageUtilization: {{ .Values.autoscaling.targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage }}
    {{- end }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the problem was with the `replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}` definition. It seems that, if you are using HPA, `replicas` can't be used. I removed this line and the HPA started scaling.